# numpy broadcasting between matrix and vector?

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I am learning numpy linear algerba, and I want to perform a simple calculation:
I have:

```
m = np.array([[1,2],
              [3,4],
              [5,6]]
v = np.array([10,20,30])
```

what I want to calculate/output:

```
[ [1/10, 2/10], 
  [3/20, 4/20],
  [5/30, 6/30]]
```

basically to perform a element-wise division between each row of m and each element of v

I can probably do that via some for loop, but I'd like to know the "proper" ways of doing it.

I am sensing it has something to do with the broadcasting but that's it.

Thanks.

Comment: thanks it is exactly what I want

Comment: Link to numpy's [outer product](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) in case you came here looking for it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to align the elements of `v` to the first axis of `m`. One way to do so would be to extend `v` to a 2D array with [`np.newaxis/None`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) and then [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) comes into play when performing elementwise division. Also, since both inputs are integer arrays and you are performing division, you need to convert one of them into a float before performing the elementwise divison. Thus, the final implementation would be -

```
m/v[:,None].astype(float)
```

You can avoid the conversion to floating point array at *user-level* if you use NumPy's true division func [`np.true_divide`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.true_divide.html) that takes care of the floating point conversion *under the hood*. So, the implementation with it would be -

```
np.true_divide(m,v[:,None])
```

Sample run -

```
In [203]: m
Out[203]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])

In [204]: v
Out[204]: array([10, 20, 30])

In [205]: m/v[:,None].astype(float)
Out[205]: 
array([[ 0.1       ,  0.2       ],
       [ 0.15      ,  0.2       ],
       [ 0.16666667,  0.2       ]])

In [206]: np.true_divide(m,v[:,None])
Out[206]: 
array([[ 0.1       ,  0.2       ],
       [ 0.15      ,  0.2       ],
       [ 0.16666667,  0.2       ]])
```